# IEnumerable.Select() when attribute is known only at runtime

Tags: c#, linq, select

Say I have a data class like this and a list of its objects:

```
public class DataSet
{
    public int A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
    public double C { get; set; }
}

var data = new List<DataSet>
{
    new DataSet() { A = 1, B = "One", C = 1.1 },
    new DataSet() { A = 2, B = "Two", C = 2.2 },
    new DataSet() { A = 3, B = "Three", C = 3.3 }
};
```

I would like to do a `Select()` on the list, based on different properties. For example, if I need a list of property `A`, I could do this easily:

```
var listA = data.Select(x => x.A).ToList();
```

All good so far.

But in my program, I need to do the above, only, I wouldn't know whether I need a list of `A` or `B` or `C` until runtime. This 'knowledge' of what to select is stored in a list of strings, and I need to iterate it and extract only the appropriate lists. Something like this:

```
// GetKeys() will return the keys that I need to extract.
// So at one time keyList could have "A" and "B", another time "B" and "C" etc.
List<string> keyList = GetKeys();

foreach (var key in keyList)
{
    // What do I do here?
    data.Select(x =>???).ToList();
}
```

Is this possible at all? I'm fine with even a non-LINQ solution, if it achieves my goal.

---

**EDIT:
Clarifying the requirement.**

The end result I want is a separate list based on each 'key' mentioned above. So, something like

`List<List<object>>`

The `count` in outer list would be the `count` of `keyList`.
The inner list would have as many items as in `DataSet`.

Comment: Would a hard-coded solution work or do you want a completely dynamic function?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto a generic function would obviously be the nicer solution, but if not possible I will even consider a hard coded one.

Comment: Each data type is different (int, string, double). How do you intend to store the result of the Select?

Comment: Based on the `key` I know the data type. But I could also use `List<object>`

Comment: You could look into building an expression tree of the desired property.

Comment: @Nkosi how would I go about that? Below answer by Rui solves my problem, but I'm interested in knowing more about your solution.

Comment: @Sach added expression tree example to compliment  already provided answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would probably not be the most efficient solution, but you could use Reflection for a fully dynamic solution:

```
private static List<List<object>> SelectDynamicData<T>(IEnumerable<T> data, List<string> properties)
{
    // get the properties only once per call
    // this isn't fast
    var wantedProperties = typeof(T)
        .GetProperties()
        .Where(x => properties.Contains(x.Name))
        .ToArray();

    var result = new Dictionary<string, List<object>>();

    foreach (var item in data)
    {
        foreach (var wantedProperty in wantedProperties)
        {
            if (!result.ContainsKey(wantedProperty.Name))
            {
                result.Add(wantedProperty.Name, new List<object>());
            }

            result[wantedProperty.Name].Add(wantedProperty.GetValue(item));
        }
    }

    return result.Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
}
```

And, of course, you'd need to do a double foreach or a LINQ query to print that. For example:

```
var data = new List<DataSet>
{
    new DataSet() { A = 1, B = "One", C = 1.1 },
    new DataSet() { A = 2, B = "Two", C = 2.2 },
    new DataSet() { A = 3, B = "Three", C = 3.3 }
};

var selectedData = SelectDynamicData(data, new List<string> { "A", "C" });

foreach (var list in selectedData)
{
    foreach (object item in list)
    {
        Console.Write(item + ", ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: Yes this seems to be a good solution as well. Could you elaborate why this might be better than the other solution? That solutions works for me as well.

Comment: I see, agreed, this looks to be a more efficient solution. Thanks!

Comment: On second thoughts though, this quite isn't what I want. I want a separate list for each property, whereas this gives me a list of dictionaries combining them.

Comment: @Sach you should edit the question to clarify exactly what it is you want so these kinds of confusions can be avoided

Comment: Good idea, done. @CamiloTerevinto, I've updated the question, and your updated answer isn't still what I am looking for, although efficiency wise it's definitely better.

Comment: @Sach I had to stop using LINQ as it only made it harder to understand, look at the update. BTW, I deleted the old comments

Comment: Checked it out, and this works as I want. I am dealing with about 20-30K data items in my actual program, so I might run 3 sets with the three solutions and will update you guys.

Answer (score 3):

Using [Creating Expression Trees by Using the API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt654263.aspx#Anchor_1) you can build an expression tree to represent the linq query you were hard coding in order to make it more dynamic.

```
Expression<Func<TModel, object>> GetPropertyExpression<TModel>(string propertyName) {
    // Manually build the expression tree for 
    // the lambda expression v => v.PropertyName.

    // (TModel v) =>
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TModel), "v");
    // (TModel v) => v.PropertyName
    var property = Expression.Property(parameter, propertyName);
    // (TModel v) => (object) v.PropertyName
    var cast = Expression.Convert(property, typeof(object));

    var expression = Expression.Lambda<Func<TModel, object>>(cast, parameter);
    return expression;
}
```

Review the comments to understand the building of the expression tree.

This now can be used with the data to extract the desired result.

Following similar to what was provided in another answer it would be simplified to

```
List<List<object>> SelectDynamicData<T>(IEnumerable<T> data, List<string> properties) {
    return properties
        .Select(_ => data.Select(GetPropertyExpression<T>(_).Compile()).ToList())
        .ToList();
}
```

Both methods are displayed in the following example

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1() {
    var data = new List<DataSet>
    {
        new DataSet() { A = 1, B = "One", C = 1.1 },
        new DataSet() { A = 2, B = "Two", C = 2.2 },
        new DataSet() { A = 3, B = "Three", C = 3.3 }
    };
    var propertyKnownAtRuntime = "A";
    var expression = GetPropertyExpression<DataSet>(propertyKnownAtRuntime);

    var listA = data.Select(expression.Compile()).ToList();
    //Produces
    // { 1, 2, 3}

    var listAC = SelectDynamicData(data, new List<string> { "A", "C" });
    //Produces
    //{
    //  { 1, 2, 3},
    //  { 1.1, 2.2, 3.3 }
    //}                
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this makes much more sense. I thought of something like this, but couldn't figure it out for what I originally thought the OP was asking

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to expression trees so it'd take a bit of time for me to understand, but if everyone agrees that this is the best solution I'd accept this in the interest of making SO better.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I was in the same boat, all this time I was building up a totally different answer which I had to abandon due to confusion in OP. I was building a new object like `new { A = v.A, C = v.C }` based on passed properties, but had to change course.

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection, for example

```
        string key = "A";

        var query = data.Select(x =>
        {
            var prop = x.GetType().GetProperty(key); //NOTE: if key does not exist this will return null
            return prop.GetValue(x);
        });

        foreach (var value in query)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(value); //will print 1, 2, 3
        }
```

Comment: Sweet, this is exactly what I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: @Sach No problem, can you accept as the answer then?

Comment: And how would this work for multiple properties? I'm not sure how this helps you @Sach

Comment: I don't understand - I could do this while iterating over my `keyList`?

Comment: @Sach Sure, then you need to build an object out of it, and then access it

Comment: I'm doing something similar to the following. But I'd be interested in knowing if you have a better solution. https://dotnetfiddle.net/w9sarU

Comment: @Sach That enumerates over `data` for each property you have, that doesn't sound at all like what you want